# php-uuid extends install error? what's wrong?

Tags: php

I install uuid extends on mac. before i install ossp-uuid.
but there are errors when make exec.
how to fix this ?
thank you!

> ```
> /Users/houziqiang/sapp/uuid-1.0.4/uuid.c:93:43: error: use of undeclared identifier
>       'UUID_TYPE_DCE_TIME'
>         REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("UUID_TYPE_TIME", UUID_TYPE_DCE_TIME, CONST_PERSISTE...
>                                                  ^
> /Users/houziqiang/sapp/uuid-1.0.4/uuid.c:94:42: error: use of undeclared identifier
>       'UUID_TYPE_DCE_RANDOM'
>         REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("UUID_TYPE_DCE", UUID_TYPE_DCE_RANDOM, CONST_PERSIST...
>                                                 ^
> /Users/houziqiang/sapp/uuid-1.0.4/uuid.c:95:43: error: use of undeclared identifier
>       'UUID_TYPE_DCE_TIME'
>         REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("UUID_TYPE_NAME", UUID_TYPE_DCE_TIME, CONST_PERSISTE...
>                                                  ^
> /Users/houziqiang/sapp/uuid-1.0.4/uuid.c:96:45: error: use of undeclared identifier
>       'UUID_TYPE_DCE_RANDOM'
>         REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("UUID_TYPE_RANDOM", UUID_TYPE_DCE_RANDOM, CONST_PERS...
>                                                    ^
> /Users/houziqiang/sapp/uuid-1.0.4/uuid.c:169:9: error: use of undeclared identifier
>       'UUID_TYPE_DCE_TIME'
>           case UUID_TYPE_DCE_TIME:
>                ^
> /Users/houziqiang/sapp/uuid-1.0.4/uuid.c:172:9: error: use of undeclared identifier
>       'UUID_TYPE_DCE_RANDOM'
>           case UUID_TYPE_DCE_RANDOM:
>                ^
> /Users/houziqiang/sapp/uuid-1.0.4/uuid.c:354:14: warning: implicit declaration of function
>       'uuid_time' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>         RETURN_LONG(uuid_time(u, NULL));
>                     ^
> 1 warning and 6 errors generated.
> make: *** [uuid.lo] Error 1`enter code here`
> ```

Comment: Have a try googling your problem - this seems to be broken for a long time now, and the PECL package has not seen an update for three years. Maybe, you want to use another way for this? https://github.com/ramsey/uuid does a good job

Comment: Lol, ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Provides the PECL UUID extension for use with the PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator)